# disabling the link button in menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my fiddle where I created menu. I want to keep the first link enabled and rest to be disabled.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/Sv3Vm/)

It should look like when we take mouse off that link. I want to disable `Green` and `Red` links.

**HTML**

```
<div class="home-content">
    <div class="menu-bar">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li data-color="#00f" class="active"><a href="#">Blue<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
            <li data-color="#0f0"><a href="#">Green<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
            <li data-color="#f00"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
        </ul>                        
    </div>
</div>

<label id="l1"> Change color </label>
```

Which css part handles this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it appear to be disabled, but you cannot actually disable the link using just CSS. You need JavaScript/HTML like Kevin said.

Make sure you add the disabled class for this to work, like so:

```
<div class="home-content">
    <div class="menu-bar">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li data-color="#00f" class="active"><a href="#">Blue<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
        <li data-color="#0f0" class="disabled"><a href="#">Green<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
        <li data-color="#f00" class="disabled"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
    </ul>                        
    </div>
</div>
```

and then in your css:

```
.disabled > a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

It looks like it isn't a link, but it still is. This is as best as you can do with just pure CSS

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7kPY/1/)

Edit: Removed color change

Comment: Hey thanks, this should work but it does ot show effect see http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/Sv3Vm/3/ it should by default show dark gray

Comment: bg color of that button should also be black

Comment: Make sure to mark an answer as a solution to your problem if your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `class="disabled"` to the `li` elements to get the disabled visual effect.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li data-color="#00f" class="active"><a href="#">Blue<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
  <li data-color="#0f0" class="disabled"><a href="#">Green<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
  <li data-color="#f00" class="disabled"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
</ul>
```

See the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-disabled-links) documentation on how to disable the tabs. Take note it just applies CSS, and you will have to disable functionality of the a tag as well.